# Assign stored procedure to variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure called `Decryptpaswd` and I want to assign the result from the procedure to a variable called `query` so that I can use it in switch statement.

How can I do this?

```
public void ValidateUser()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(var3);

    String sql= "Decryptpaswd";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
}

try
{
    conn.Open();

    **switch (query)**
    {
        case "AA": Response.Redirect("Home");
                   break;

        case "BB": Response.Redirect("Home1");
                   break;

        case "CC": Response.Redirect("Home2");
                   break;

        default: Response.Redirect("LogIn.aspx");
                 break;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** The Stored Proc accepts two things, UserName and Password.. If the entered Username and password is right, then Rolename is returned.. So this rolename is used in the Case statements..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Decryptpaswd] 
    (
    @Username varchar(10),
    @Pasword varchar(256)
    )
    as

    SELECT 
     Rolename FROM Users
        WHERE Username = @Username AND DecryptByCert(----('---'),Pass, @Paswd)= @Pasword
     }
```

Comment: `and I want to assign that SP called "Decryptpaswd" to a variable called "query"` - what does that mean? Do you mean you want to invoke the SP and do something with the result?

Comment: use `using (SqlDataReader SqlReader = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader())` to execute it, then get your `query` back by `SqlReader.GetString(0)` after `SqlReader.Read()`

Comment: @Eric `(string)cmd.ExecuteScalar()` would be easier...

Comment: @Marc right, assume only 1 result there

Comment: Fact: if you can **decrypt** what you have as the password, you are doing it wrong. You should be *encrypting* passwords; you shouldn't be using a 1-way hash

Comment: @MarcGravell I understand.., But my boss told me this is simple app that doesn't need authentication and stuff.. So Encryption and Decryption is done at the Database level..

Answer (score 3):

It *sounds* like your SP returns (selects) a string, and you want to do something with the result... if so:

```
string role;
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(var3))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Decryptpaswd", conn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Username", username);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Pasword", password);
    conn.Open();
    query = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
switch(role) {
   ...
}
```

You probably also want to add some parameters to `cmd`.

Comment: Yes I need to add 2 parameters.. It gives an error: Procedure or function 'Decryptpaswd' expects parameter '@Username', which was not supplied.

Comment: I am not adding anything.. My Stored Proc here, is selecting Roles that in the table, based on Uname and Password.. So I want "roles" to be result

Comment: @TinTin so... add the `@Username` param; now: what is `roles`, because you didn't mention that in the question?

Comment: @Marc.. I have edited the question .. How will I actually add Username params?

Comment: username and password in cmd.parameters are telling it doesn't exists. I changed with my textbox control TextBox1 and Textbox2.Text.. Even then its giving an error- `Procedure or function 'Decryptpaswd' expects parameter '@Username', which was not supplied.`

Comment: @TinTin the only way the parameter value will be omitted is if you've given it a `null`. Check what the values are when you add them.

Comment: @TinTin then double check you haven't got a typo in the parameter name; basically, if `username` is a non-null string, then it will send the parameter value.

Comment: @banging no, the `@` is entirely optional at the sender - it works identically with/without. This is intentional, so that DB-agnostic code can work against the abstract DbCommand etc without needing to know whether that particular software (Oracle, Informix, SQL Server, SQLite, etc) uses `@` vs `:` vs `$` etc to name the parameters.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. I was trying to explain why it wasn't working for him. It has to be a typo then..